# Kohana - rules method throwing error

Tags: php, kohana

I have created the following method in order to do the validation on the submitted data.

```
public function validate_create($array) {

    $array = Validation::factory($array)
        -> rules('username', $this - > _rules['username']);

    return $array;
}
```

The rules is defined as

```
protected $_rules = array(
    'username' = > array(
        'not_empty' = > NULL,
        'min_length' = > array(6),
        'max_length' = > array(32),
    )
);
```

The code is throwing the following exception when trying to execute the check() method.

> ErrorException [ Warning ]: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1
>   to be a valid callback, no array or string given

Can any one advice how to solve this issue?

In signup.php the input field for username is defined as

> < ?php echo Form::label('user_name','Username')? >  < ?php echo
>   Form::input('username'); ? >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for building the `Validation` object directly is different from that of your `$_rules` array.

You can see the correct method signature and definition [documented here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Validation#rules), and it'd probably be a good idea to also read the [signature for `Validation::rule`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Validation#rule).

In short, the `rules()` method wants an list of arrays, where for each inner array the first element is the validation function and the second an array of parameters to pass to it.

e.g.

```
$rules = array(
    array('not_empty', NULL),
    array('min_length', array(':value', 6))
);

$v = Validation::factory($values)
    ->rules('fieldname', $rules);
```

Note that this is different than the `$_rules` array (map) format that you are attempting to use where the key is the validation function and the parameters are the values.

Aslo, is there any reason you're building your own validation function instead of using the [`ORM::rules()` method](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/validation) of validation?

Comment: I was just trying to learn kohana from a kohana book( bi Jason D. Straughan) I downloaded. I tried out one of his examples. Thanks for your time.